# Kali Linux won't install Wise Tiger Wireless Adapter Driver

Tags: linux, drivers, kali-linux, wireless-adapter, makefile

I have currently dual booted Kali Linux and I have a Wise Tiger WT-AC9006 wireless adapter. I have downloaded the driver from the company site and attempted to install it via the command line:

```
./install.sh
```

However, I continue to get the following error:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:273: /home/bballboy8/Desktop/linux/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1696: /home/bballboy8/Desktop/linux/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:1551: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Furthermore, when I ran lsusb, the device appears as device 008:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b449 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:0797 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse 200
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I used the GitHub repository https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux and got the following error when I went to make the file.

```
/home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c: In function ‘rtw_proc_create_entry’:
/home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c:73:67: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create_data’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   73 |  entry = proc_create_data(name,  S_IFREG|S_IRUGO|S_IWUGO, parent, fops, data);
      |                                                                   ^~~~
      |                                                                   |
      |                                                                   const struct file_operations *
In file included from /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/include/../os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.h:23,
                 from /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/include/osdep_intf.h:123,
                 from /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/include/drv_types.h:107,
                 from /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c:21:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/include/linux/proc_fs.h:59:31: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct file_operations *’
   59 | extern struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:273: /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1696: /home/bballboy8/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-kali1-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:1622: modules] Error 2
```

How would I go about adjusting the files in order to make this work properly?

Comment: So there's no wifi driver available for your hardware in the official software repositories?

Comment: http://www.wise-tiger.com/English/html/865412507.html This is where are I got the wifi driver from.

Comment: That's not an official kali repository... Browsing the web for a driver like this is only done if all other options are exhausted without luck... Official packages are made for your distro. That driver download is not...

Comment: I will add to the question for the official github distro and the error that comes with that.

Comment: That driver you downloaded is made for a kernel that is way older than the one you're running... Why don't you just check the kali repositories for a driver compatible with yourr wifi-card chipset?